# How to solve the glm label redefined error

Tags: c++, opengl, glm-math

I have the following code to rotate an object.

```
glm:vec3 myRotationAxis(1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
  glm:mat4 rot = glm::rotate(glm::mat4(1.0), 3.14f, myRotationAxis);
```

Why does it give me the glm label redefined error?

Comment: [tag:glm] != [tag:glm-math]

Comment: There are typos in your code: `glm:vec3`, `glm:mat4`

Answer (score 1):

You're using colons, when you should be using the scope resolution operator: `::`. `a::b` says to look for the symbol `b` inside the scope `a`. In your cases, the symbols are classes and the scope is the `glm` namespace defined by the `glm` library. Write instead:

```
glm::vec3 myRotationAxis(1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
  glm::mat4 rot = glm::rotate(glm::mat4(1.0), 3.14f, myRotationAxis);
```

In the code you provided, the single colon defines a label "glm", but it does it twice, which causes an error.